# Query filter ArgumentException when trying to extending OU principal

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, active-directory, directoryservices

I am try to create extension of principal for organizationalUnit using this code below

```
[DirectoryRdnPrefix("OU")]
[DirectoryObjectClass("organizationalUnit")]
public class OrganizationalUnitPrincipal : Principal
{
    public OrganizationalUnitPrincipal(PrincipalContext Context_p)
    {
        PropertyInfo contextRaw = this.GetType().BaseType.GetProperty("ContextRaw",
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        contextRaw.SetValue(this, Context_p, null);
    }
}
```

But it throws the following error:

```
System.ArgumentException: Persisted Principal objects cannot be used as query filters.
```

This error occurs when I try retrieve organizationalUnit attributes and properties.

Can this work or not?

I want to achieve the same as show on this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/site/bb384372

Comment: You tagged C#4 and. NET3.5. Which is it? (not that that neccesarily makes any difference for the answer...)

Comment: Sorry getting late here I will the .net-3.5 tag

Comment: this is scary. why are you trying to inject something?

Comment: Using reflection to set private members is certainly wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the theorical point of view, I think that what you want to do has no sense. It's explained in the article you point, but it's not so clear. The concept of `Principal` is based on the `Directory Schema` wich discribe objects you can add to ActiveDirectory.

*The Principal, AuthenticablePrincipal, UserPrincipal, ComputerPrincipal, and GroupPrincipal classes can all be extended to create custom objects that extend the object model*.

But in LDAP in general and it's the case in Active-Directory the class `organizationalUnit` is not a subclass of the `user` class, but just a subclass of the `top` class.

In other words : on the conceptual point of view you can note that a `Principal` is kind of user (Yes in Microsoft point of view computers are users, they open sessions onto the domain like the users) and `organizationalUnit` is a kind of organizational box (like a directory in a file system), so the second one do not extent the first one.

---

Edited

Here is a subclass of DirectoryEntry that do what you want :

```
class ClsOrganizationalUnit : DirectoryEntry
{
  private DirectoryEntry de;

  public string Description
  {
    get { return (string)de.Properties["description"][0]; }
    set { de.Properties["description"].Value = value;
          de.CommitChanges();
        }
  }

  public ClsOrganizationalUnit(string dn, string username, string password)
  {
    de = new DirectoryEntry(dn, username, password);
  }


}

class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    ClsOrganizationalUnit ou = new ClsOrganizationalUnit("LDAP://192.168.183.100:389/ou=Monou,dc=dom,dc=fr", "jpb", "pwd");

    /* Set the attribute */
    ou.Description = "The description you want";
    Console.WriteLine("Here is your OU description : {0}", ou.Description);

    /* Remove the attribute */
    ou.Description = null;
  }
}
```

Comment: This website and explaination got me on this track http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/565579/system-directoryservices-accountmanagement-principal-throws-nullreferenceexception

Comment: People (even Microsoft one) can write what they want, but in my understanding a principal has nothing to do with an OU.

Comment: Fair enough, it clear to me that this is the wrong path. But If I want to get something like that for an OU. Can I extend the directoryentry class?

Comment: You can just work with directoryentry, or subclass it to provide organizationalUNit properties.

Comment: Do you have an example of subclass the directoryentry. I am trying tot figure it out but still no luck.  The problem is that I want to access _description_ property in the same way the **Name** or **Path** property can be accessed.  Not like _DirectoryEntry.Property["description"].Value_

Comment: I edit my answer to add the begining of the class you seem to look for.

Comment: Thx I was almost there, but forget to create a new directoryEntry.