# System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal with multiple DirectoryObjectClassAttribute

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, active-directory

We have and Active Directory Ligthweight Directory Services (AD LDS) synced with an Active Directory using userProxy obect. We also create user class object in the AD LDS.

The UserPrincipal object seems limited to user class object in AD. I know I can create a userProxyPrincipal based on userProxy class objects. But I want to create a single object to handle both cases.

Since in the documentation of the [DirectoryObjectClassAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.directoryobjectclassattribute.aspx) it's specified that you can use multiple DirectoryObjectClassAttribute I'm wondering how I can achieve this.

If I specify on my own UserPrincipal object with two attributes (one with "user" and one with "userProxy") it compiles, but match only object with the same class as the first one specified. (I tried to swap them, and it's always the first one that matches)

If I specify two DirectoryPropertyAttribute on a property, now it's matches only object with the same class as the second one.

So I see that it can transfer from one to another, but I don't understand how to implement it right.

Any suggestions ?

(Sorry for the lack of code exemple, I'm at home and will post them first thing tomorrow at work)

**Update - Add code Snipet**

Here's my UserProxyPrincipal class

```
namespace System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
{
    [DirectoryRdnPrefix("CN")]
    [DirectoryObjectClass("userProxy")]
    [DirectoryObjectClass("user")]
    public class UserProxyPrincipal : UserPrincipal
    {
        public UserProxyPrincipal(PrincipalContext context)
            : base(context) { }
        public UserProxyPrincipal(PrincipalContext context, string samAccountName, string password, bool enabled)
            : base(context, samAccountName, password, enabled) { }

        public static new UserProxyPrincipal FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext context, string identityValue)
        {
            return (UserProxyPrincipal)FindByIdentityWithType(context, typeof(UserProxyPrincipal), identityValue);
        }
        public static new UserProxyPrincipal FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext context, IdentityType identityType, string identityValue)
        {
            return (UserProxyPrincipal)FindByIdentityWithType(context, typeof(UserProxyPrincipal), identityType, identityValue);
        }

        [DirectoryProperty("objectSid")]
        public string ObjectSid
        {
            get
            {
                var values = ExtensionGet("objectSid");
                return ((values != null) && (values.Length > 0) ? values[0].ToString() : null);
            }
            set { ExtensionSet("objectSid", value); }
        }

        [DirectoryProperty("name")]
        public new string Name
        {
            get
            {
                var values = ExtensionGet("name");
                return ((values != null) && (values.Length > 0) ? values[0].ToString() : null);
            }
            set { ExtensionSet("name", value); }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a program to test it

```
namespace FunWith.MTO.Framework.Security
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.ApplicationDirectory, "servername.some.domain:636", "DC=dev,DC=local", ContextOptions.SimpleBind);
            Console.WriteLine("Log AdamUser : {0}", context.ValidateCredentials("AdamUser", "somePassword%"));
            Console.WriteLine("Log AdProxiedUser : {0}", context.ValidateCredentials("AdProxiedUser", "somePassword;"));
            var p = UserProxyPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, "AdProxiedUser");
            var t = UserProxyPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, "AdamUser");
            Console.WriteLine("User AdProxiedUser is {0}" ,p != null ? p.DistinguishedName : "null");
            Console.WriteLine("User AdamUser is {0}", t != null ? t.DistinguishedName : "null");

        }
    }
}
```

That's my Output With the code as posted :

```
    Log AdamUser : True
    Log AdProxiedUser : True
    User AdProxiedUser is CN=AdProxiedUser,OU=Usagers,DC=dev,DC=local
    User AdamUser is null
```

Now if I swap the two DirectoryObjectClass on my UserProxyPrincipal like that :

```
    [DirectoryObjectClass("user")]
    [DirectoryObjectClass("userProxy")]
```

I have this result (swapped result) :

```
    Log AdamUser : True
    Log AdProxiedUser : True
    User AdProxiedUser is null
    User AdamUser is CN=AdamUser,OU=AdamUsers,OU=Usagers,DC=dev,DC=local
```

Seeing that I can define two different DirectoryObjectClassAttribute, I start thinking that may be I have to set tow diffrent DirectoryPropertyAttribute like that :

```
    [DirectoryProperty("objectSid")]
    [DirectoryProperty("objectSid")]
    public string ObjectSid
        [...]

    [DirectoryProperty("name")]
    [DirectoryProperty("name")]
    public new string Name
        [...]
```

Resulting in a swapped result one again (I kept the swapped DirectoryObjectClassAttribute)

```
    Log AdamUser : True
    Log AdProxiedUser : True
    User AdProxiedUser is CN=AdProxiedUser,OU=Usagers,DC=dev,DC=local
    User AdamUser is null
```

Hoping that will help understand what's my problem

Oh and by the way, if I remove the double attributes, keeping only this one :

```
    [DirectoryObjectClass("userProxy")]
```

And specifically use a UserPrincipal for my AdamUser (user object class) and my UserProxyPrincipal for my AdProxiedUser (userProxy object class) like that :

```
var p = UserProxyPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, "AdProxiedUser");
var t = UserProxy.FindByIdentity(context, "AdamUser");
```

Both are Matched. See result :

```
    Log AdamUser : True
    Log AdProxiedUser : True
    User AdProxiedUser is CN=AdProxiedUser,OU=Usagers,DC=dev,DC=local
    User AdamUser is CN=AdamUser,OU=AdamUsers,OU=Usagers,DC=dev,DC=local
```

Answer (score 4):

I know this was posted a while ago (2 years). But I stepped in to a similar problem I wanted to solve. I wanted to have a "GeneralPrincipal" inheriting from the base class "Principal" to be able to query for computer, group and user at the same time.

First, I guess only one of the DirectoryObjectClassAttributes are used (class System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ExtensionHelper in Reflector):

```
internal static string ReadStructuralObjectClass(Type principalType)
{
    DirectoryObjectClassAttribute[] attributeArray = (DirectoryObjectClassAttribute[]) Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(principalType, typeof(DirectoryObjectClassAttribute), false);
    if (attributeArray == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    string objectClass = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < attributeArray.Length; i++)
    {
        if (!attributeArray[i].Context.HasValue && (objectClass == null))
        {
            objectClass = attributeArray[i].ObjectClass;
        }
    }
    return objectClass;
}
```

How I solved it:

I "fooled" the reader of the attribute by doing like this (look at the DirectoryObjectClassAttribute):

```
[DirectoryRdnPrefix("CN")]
[DirectoryObjectClass("*)(|(objectClass=computer)(objectClass=group)(objectClass=user)")]
public class GeneralPrincipal : Principal
{
    private static readonly FieldInfo _unpersistedField = typeof(Principal).GetField("unpersisted", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    #region Constructors

    public GeneralPrincipal(PrincipalContext context)
    {
        if(context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");

        this.ContextRaw = context;
        _unpersistedField.SetValue(this, true);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Hope this help someone

Regards Hans

Comment: Kinderg, `[DirectoryObjectClass("*)(|(objectClass=computer)(objectClass=group)(objectClass=user)")]` This saved me so much time! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Even if this question has sense for me I think that the answer is not far from the one I give to [Query filter ArgumentException when trying to extending OU principal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8441228/608772).

The point is that Active-Directory (and ADAM/LDS), like other directories is built with a concept of class hierarchy. So you can use DirectoryObjectClass to specify a class in a branch of the schema hierachical tree but not two classes in different branches.

As far as I understand, to do what you want to do, userProxy class have to be a subclass of user class (or the reverse order) in your Directory schema. In other words you try to build using C# a class that inherit from two classes (in different branches) in your Directory schema, and as C# Directories don't support multiple inheritance.

Writting so, I don't answer your question, but try to explain why it does'nt work.

Comment: Interesting point, I'll check up on that and see if it's doable and if so if it solves my problem.